# Executing multiple modules using a button in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to execute two module sub in excel VBA through a third module, through a button.

The subs are defined in unique module files as:

```
Public Sub MinPenCheck()

'code here, if statements, variables etc. 

End Sub
```

And:

```
Public Sub InputCheck()

'code here, if statements, variables etc. 

End Sub
```

I defined a third module as follows:

```
Public Sub DesignCheck()
   Call InputCheck 'Macro1
   Call MinPenCheck 'Macro2
End Sub
```

And I inputed a button in my spreadsheet, assigning the above macro to it. When I press the button, the other two modules are not executing. I am getting the error "Expected variable or procedure, not module".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can remove `Call` from `DesignCheck` although this is not the source of your issue.

Comment: Are your modules named `MinPenCheck` or `InputCheck`?

Comment: According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/expected-variable-or-procedure-not-module) it looks like the name may be ambiguous. i.e. you named your modules the same as the macros. If so, you will need to change that

Comment: @BigBen Yes, they are

Comment: Check if the module name is equal the sub name

Comment: Change them to something else.

Comment: It worked ! Thank you all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct is

```
Public Sub DesignCheck()
   Call InputCheck.InputCheck() 'Macro1
   Call MinPenCheck.MinPenCheck() 'Macro2
End Sub
```

Comment: Or better, name the modules something else.

Comment: And you don't need to use the word `Call` anymore.